# Read Only Headers of Http POST request(with huge entity body) in Memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am using IIS 7/7.5. I have a page where users can upload huge data. Sometimes, I required to read the POST body and sometime not. Is there is any way in IIS/ASP.NET to defer reading the POST entity body until I signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely read the request headers without worrying about the file size. Let me elaborate. Consider the following html page allowing to upload files to the `/upload.aspx` endpoint:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/upload.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

We could then have a generic handler:

```
public class Upload: IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        var response = context.Response;
        response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        response.Write(request.Headers.ToString());
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

and then ensure that we have increased the request limits in web.config in order to allow huge files to be uploaded:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10485760" />
```

and:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Now let's suppose that the user selects a very large file to upload (say 5GB) and hits the submit button. The `ProcessRequest` method of your generic handler will be hit immediately meaning that you could access the headers very quickly:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var fileSize = context.Request.ContentLength;
}
```

And if you wanted to read the contents of this file you could start reading from the input stream of the file which will obviously take a lot of time until the entire file is uploaded:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // We reach at that point pretty fast and we can read the headers here
    // and determine for example the total bytes to be uploaded
    var fileSize = context.Request.ContentLength;

    // now we can start reading the file which would obviously take quite a lot of time:
    context.Request.Files[0].InputStream.Read(...)
}
```

But then you might ask yourself: but if the `ProcessRequest` method is hit immediately after the user hits the submit button where is the uploaded file at that time? Actually as the bytes arrive from the client IIS is chunking them in temporary files (it is not in memory, you should not worry about that) and the InputStream is pointing to this location, so that when you start reading from it, you will actually be reading data that IIS has already received from the client and made available for you. Those temporary files will be created when you start reading from the input stream. So that's where you should be careful because when you are reading from this stream you are loading the data in memory. So if you can have potentially very large data coming from the client you should always read and process it in chunks. If you wanted to store the uploaded file on the server you should read the input stream in chunks and write those chunks to an output file on your server (or if you are using .NET 4.0, simply use the `Stream.CopyTo` method).

Comment: Thanks. Is this mean that Server request entity body on-demand. I mean that server will defer reading the POST body until we access Request.Form/File/InputStream/BufferedStream/BufferlessStream.

Comment: @user960567, yes, IIS is deferring the loading of the request body. If you never read from `Request.Form/File/InputStream` in your handler, the body (or chunks of it) won't be loaded. You don't need to worry about the implementation. What you should know is that IIS is providing you with this mechanism.

Comment: Darin one thing confuses me, you are saying that IIS save the POST entity body in temporary file. Can you provide me a link of this information? Because lot of sources are saying that ASP.NET/IIS load request entity body on demand.

Comment: No need to provide you with references. If you are using ASP.NET 2.0, simply look at the `Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.CodegenDirInternal, "uploads");` folder and you're gonna see the temporary file generated by ASP.NET. And if you are using ASP.NET 4.0, look at `Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.CodegenDir, "uploads");`. Of course this will happen when you start reading the body, not before. Sorry if my explanation was not clear enough.

Comment: Thanks, BTW I am talking ASP.NET(available in Native IIS as well) ReadEntityBody about, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest.readentitybody%28v=vs.110%29.aspx which clearly state that from client. System.Web internally used it.